# terraform external data not returning bash output

Tags: bash, curl, terraform, jq, digital-ocean

I, trying to return bash execution through Terraform `data "external"`, but have error:

```
│ jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
│ 
│ 
│   with data.external.fetchssh,
│   on dovpccloud.tf line 31, in data "external" "fetchssh":
│   31: data "external" "fetchssh" {
```

however bash script is successfully return ssh-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
do_token=`echo "var.do-token" | terraform -chdir=/input console`
curl -X GET -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${do_token//\"}" "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/keys?page=1" | jq -r --arg queryname "User's key" '.ssh_keys[] | select(.name == $queryname).public_key'
```

it returns common ssh-rsa.
After data "external" I would use this in droplet resource:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  image  = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  name   = "web-1"
  region = "lon1"
  size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  tags = [digitalocean_tag.devops.id, digitalocean_tag.your_email.id]
  ssh_keys = [digitalocean_ssh_key.user.id, data.external.fetchssh]
}
```

I suspect the problem is in program execution of internal terraform method, but can't get what.

Comment: What is the example output of your `curl`? Without that its rather difficult to speculate why your `jq` fails.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple modules that have been built to handle this situation and make it a lot easier to work with. [This](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Invicton-Labs/shell-data/external/latest) is my preferred one for a shell data source; use it with the `curl` command (forget `jq`), then use `jsondecode` on the `stdout` response and access whichever fields you need.

Alternatively, instead of using `curl` you can use the [HTTP provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http) (if there's a way to get your token from within terraform).